# UITableView (IOS) trying to delete but never get the delete button to show up

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I know there's a lot of questions like this one out there, but I've followed a couple of them and none of them could lead me to the answer.

Probably it's just something stupid and obvious I'm missing but I can't get it...

So what I'm doing is, I have a normal UITableViewController. In the table I want to display all files the user downloaded via my app and give him the opportunity to delete the files as well. Everything works fine - I can list up the files, and when clicked another view opens to display the file.

But I never can get the row to delete something. I swiped all possible ways but I never even get the delete button! I have implemented the canEditRowAtIndexPath function to make it return YES (although it shouldn't be necessary, I've made tons of apps where I deleted rows and never needed the function):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

My actual delete method is implemented like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, [files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        BOOL success = false;

        if ([fileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:fileName]) {
            success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fileName error:&error];
        }

        if (success) {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [files removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            [Functions msg:NSLocalizedString(@"fileCantBeDeleted", @"") title:NSLocalizedString(@"fileError", @"") delegate:nil];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be complete, I can give you the code of cellForRowAtIndexpath as well:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

The NSArray "files" has been filled before, in the viewDidLoad method like this:

```
directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:nil];
```

Both directory and files are properties of my class.
As said, the whole class is just implementing a UITableViewController.
I really can't see why it wouldn't let me delete a row, but probably it's something really stupid... I just can't see it.

**EDIT**

Found the bug.

This particular TableView doesn't itself implement any methods of the PKRevealController library, but it was apparently set as the frontViewController - so there happened to be a gesture on there that I didn't know of. The controller also was not intended to be used inside a PKRevealController... I just added it in a wrong way, so I wasn't aware of that either! That's also why I forgot to include it in my question.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/issues/123 (for if anyone else might ever run into this problem).

Thanks for helping me anyway!

**EDIT**

Another possible solution I just learned about if you want to use a tableView and still keep deleting things while using a PKRevealController (without starting to get strange with UIGestureRecognizers): You can just add an edit button to trigger the view into editing mode.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: do you have any Swipe gestures on the current view?

Comment: Nope, no swipe gestures on there.

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in Xcode, do *any* of the table's delegate methods hit?  e.g. "`canEditRowAtIndexPath`"? remember that delegate is not necessarily the same thing as the table view data source.

Comment: Yes, the delegate and data source are correctly set, and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath was called correctly as well (that was the confusing part of it). Thanks @shabzco because your question led me in the right way of solving this problem, I edited the question to answer myself :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the ["`editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aeditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath%3a) into your delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return( UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete );
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't change - I still can't get it into editing mode or get a delete button...

Answer (score 3):

## Make Your tableview editable

You need to create an object of your table view ....

in .h file of the ViewController.

```
UITableView *table;
```

in .m file of the ViewController you need to set the editing mode also of the tableview...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

table.editing=YES;

[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Hope this will help you ......

Comment: Thanks, but it turned out to be another view this table was embedded in that was suppressing the UIGestures on it. I added an edit button to toggle between the editing mode of the view (it doesn't have to be in editing mode the whole time does it? :)) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, I only see you commented now. So what happened: my UITableView was embedded in another view. The library I used adds a 'sidebar' to the app like the one in the Facebook application. But by doing that, it surpresses all UIGestures, which includes the swipe gesture you usually make when you want to delete a row in the table. So that was what prevented my from deleting my row. To solve the problem while I was still using my library, I added an edit button in the toolbar to toggle to editmode, like in the standard clock application of Apple.

Comment: @testuser as far i understood your requirement,I think the swipe gesture is preventing you from deleting the row of table and it behaves the functionality of gesture, not deleting the row?Am i right....if so, i think it matters where you added the gestures,try some dos and don'ts  regarding adding the gestures.

Comment: The problem is I'm using an external library that is capturing all swipe gestures. Like the Facebook app, you won't be able to delete a row (or post, for that matter) by swiping because swiping will open the sidebar. So they implemented a button where you click and then you can choose "delete this post" (or other choices). I think that's the way to go, as when you're adding multiple different gestures depending on exactly where on the screen you swipe will be very confusing.